# Getting an alt tag to show up over an img on hover

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, alt

So I've got it working on a jsfiddle perfectly here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dxhC/32/

```
$('img', '.thumb').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().append('<div class="thumbnail-text">' + this.alt + '</div>');
}).bind({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).siblings('.thumbnail-text').show();
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).siblings('.thumbnail-text').hide(); 
  }
});
```

but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work with a wordpress gallery plug-in here:

http://www.adammichaelogden.com/my_work/

I've tried everything I can think of and I just know its probably something very simple that I'm over looking. Any help?

Comment: On wordpress gallery plugin, please check whether jquery loads or not, because when I am checking in console, it is not getting loaded, $ is undefined for me, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it seems that `$` is not accepting. I had run below code in console on your site and it worked:-

```
jQuery('img','.all-images').each(function() { 
    jQuery(this).parent().append('<div class="thumbnail-text">' + this.alt + '</div>'); 
}).bind({ mouseenter: function() { 
    jQuery(this).siblings('.thumbnail-text').show(); 
}, mouseleave: function() { 
    jQuery(this).siblings('.thumbnail-text').hide(); } 
});
```

Comment: Yeah I ran the same code you have in console and it worked but when I put it in the actual code it still doesn't work?

Comment: @AdamOgden  either you have to add this code in corresponding plug-ins jquery or you have try it to apply it anyhow before plugin jquery. Sorry i am not a word press man,.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a couple of syntax errors. You're missing the comma between `img` and `.all-images` selectors, and missing the closing `});`.

Try changing the block to this

```
$(function() {
  $('img','.all-images').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="thumbnail-text">' + this.alt + '</div>');
  }).bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).siblings('.thumbnail-text').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).siblings('.thumbnail-text').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That was a problem but wasn't the problem.

Comment: @AdamOgden the script tag is invalid. It's `<script` and needs to be `<script>`

Comment: Yep that was it. Well it was a mix of $ not being read and then that was the final touch. Beautiful.